# App Clip Card - This app clip is not currently available in your country or region

Tags: apple-appclips

I am testing App Clip on Testflight to show App Clip Card but it only shows a white Card with the message: “This app clip is not currently available in your country or region” (if using Local Expreriences, it shows normally) I have fully installed apple-app-site-association, App Clip Experience, Domain URL Status also validated ... don't understand why, is the app "Redy For Sale" new to show the Card?. I want to let customers test show App Clip Card without using Local Expreriences on Testflight If anyone knows, please help, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I done two apps with app clips. The first one only showed the app clip card after I shipped my app and the app was ready for sale. I think this needs to be done to live test the app clip card. Because my second app is still not submitted and I got the same message as yours even though my setting is in the same region.

Otherwise you have to rely on local experience and TestFlight. For TestFlight however, I think you get to only test the app clip "app" by downloading it from TestFlight (if you check TestFlight you will see the app clip separate from the full app like image below) [clip test image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2f4fJ.png) and not the whole experience (app clip card, the downloading of the app clip and the app clip it self).