# This app clip is not currently available in your country or region

Tags: ios, apple-appclips

My team and I are actively developing an app with an associated app clip, however, we are unable to test the app clip's launch on any device other than the simulator due to receiving the error: "This app clip is not currently available in your country or region" A local experience has been registered, the domain has been properly associated with the apple-app-site-association file, the experience has been registered on app store connect, and the app clip can be launched normally. (Without the advanced url invocation). If anyone could know a reason this could be happening, it would be greatly appreciated! We have tried just about everything at the moment.

Association file:

```json
{
    "applinks": {
        "details": [
             {
               "appIDs": [ "GROUPID.APPID"],
               "components": [
                 {
                    "/": "/*",
                    "comment": "Matches any URL with a path that starts with /."
                 }
               ]
             }
         ]
     },
  
      "appclips": {
          "apps": ["GROUPID.APPID.Clip"]
      }
  }
```

Comment: Same as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70892172/app-clip-card-this-app-clip-is-not-currently-available-in-your-country-or-regi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add line "paths": ["*"] after "appIDs": [ "GROUPID.APPID"] and also make sure you Added

Associated Domins in both Appclip targets and main app targets

Domins:

appclips:appcliptest.com

applinks:appcliptest.com

```
{
    "applinks": {
        "details": [
             {
               "appIDs": [ "GROUPID.APPID"],
               "paths":["*"],
               "components": [
                 {
                    "/": "/*",
                    "comment": "Matches any URL with a path that starts with /."
                 }
               ]
             }
         ]
      },
  
      "appclips": {
          "apps": ["GROUPID.APPID.Clip"]
      }
 }
```